# Keras at TF2 metrics not added

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 nightly build, on google colab.

I made simple CNN model, and than compiled it, and fit it.

Here's code:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='SAME',
                           activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='SAME',
                           activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              matrics=['accuracy'])
log_dir='./logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir,
                                                      histogram_freq=2,
                                                      write_images=True,
                                                      update_freq='batch',
                                                      profile_batch=0)
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=15,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback], validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

And it don't give me accuracy information.

I evaluated model, and it supposed to give me accuracy information, but it only gives me loss information.

I printed `model.metrics`, and it was just `[]`.

Is it bug? Or I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `metrics` as `matrics`. Change `matrics=['accuracy']` to `metrics=['accuracy']`.

Comment: Oh. Hold on. I'll test it. I think I confused it with matrix.